# Greedy Algorithem for matching numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, greedy, correctness

We have a group 'S' that contains 2n socks. each sock in the group has a color.
Colors are represented by a real positive number. [c : S -> R(+)]
It is possible for 2 socks in the group to be in the same color.

-We define **"Punishment"** of a pair of socks (a,b) like that: 
P(a,b) = |c(a)-c(b)|. (in other word the "punishment" of 2 socks of the same color is 0)

I need to describe a greedy algorithm that gets as input a group S and returns a group A that contains pairs of socks (each sock from S, is in A exactly one time) and the summarize punishment will be **minimal**. 
[summarize punishment=> the sum of punishments of all the pairs in the group]

and I need to prove that the algorithm is correct.
I'm having problem with proving my algorithm is correct,
I sorted the socks according to their numeric color value , and picked the first ones from S each time.
I tried to prove it with induction but I don't know how I need to do the 'switching' part in the optimal group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your algorithm is correct :)

Proof:
Imagine, that we have different solution to our problem which is better one than ours(we just sorted and matched nearest together). Therefore there must exist at least two pairs (a

**1)** a is in interval (c,d) and b isnt or similar to them.
(otherwise we would have this pairs in our solution).

Now lets calculate the punishment: punishment is |a-b| + |c-d|

because of our **1)** we can think about the order of our numbers such as:

**2** : a < c < b < d

**3** : a < c < d < b

**4** : c < a < b < d

**5** : c < a < d < b

Each orther is almost the same in calculations: 
we can easily prove

for example in (**2**) that |a-b| + |c-d| > |a-c| + |b-d|,

because a-b < a-c and a < c < b so |a-b| > |a-c|
c-d < b-d and c < b < d so |c-d| > |b-d|

Now if that happen, swapping those values will change this solution to even better one which is looking like in our algorithm :)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, the the given socks must be even. (there are 2n socks) so lets say
(1,10,11,12,13,14).
the best group A we can get is
{(1,10),(11,12),(13,14)} with minimal sum of punishment = 9 + 1 + 1 =11
any other combination of pairs will get a sum greater than 9.

Comment: Ok, that's change a lot :D I will edit answer to correct one